# Unable to compile conference Latex Template

Tags: compiling, templates

I am trying to start my writing my paper for a conference using the given template link below

[download latex template](https://www.conferenceabstracts.com/uploads/documents/12130/AES_149th_Convention_template_peerReviewed.zip)
[Conference website](https://www.abstractscorecard.com/cfp/submit/login.asp?EventKey=VMPLDJWE)

I am very surprise is it my own setting problem or the template problem because this conference is a well established conference, and it could not be template problem.

I had tried overleaf:
[image]

```
Package latexrelease Warning: The current package is for an older LaTeX format:

(latexrelease)                LaTeX 2019-10-01 
(latexrelease)                Obtain a newer version of this package!.

) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"

! LaTeX Error: Suspicious rollback date given.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.28 ...ase{}{2017-06-25}{graphics-2017-06-25.sty}

?
```

I had tried local PC using Texwowkrs.
[image]

Both have error, is it my setting problem?
I am new to using a template from conference, any advice and guideline will help.

I did search how to use basic TeXwork, but it working when I typed simple Latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you make the following changes:

- Find the file `aesconf.cls`.
- Make a copy and name the copy `aesconf-current.cls`. Why "current"? You'll see in a sec.
- In the file `aesconf-current.cls`, find the following line:

  ```
  \RequirePackage[2015/01/01]{latexrelease}
  ```

  Change this line to

  ```
  \RequirePackage[current]{latexrelease}
  ```

  If you don't want to be quite that bold, maybe choose `2018/12/01` as the date option.
- Save the file `aesconf-current.cls` in the directory that contains the other template files.
- In the main template file (the one that ends in .tex), change

  ```
  \documentclass[convention,peer-reviewed]{aesconf}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \documentclass[convention,peer-reviewed]{aesconf-current}
  ```

  and you should be in business.
- Finally, you may want to alert the conference organizers and inform them that (a) they're giving out a bum template and (b) they ought to provide a fix.

Comment: thanks a lot. It works. I was thinking is my setting wrong, keep looking around how to use `texmarker` and `overleaf` for whole day. Thanks for your times.